# How to ignore 'label' on the 'Elevated button'?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a button with an icon centered.

[image: This image is the current image.]

thie is my code.

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                    label: Text(''),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.red,
                      fixedSize: Size(100, 50),
                    )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you. The lable field is required for **ElevatedButton.icon** refer documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/ElevatedButton.icon.html) you can used TextButton

#### Using Container

```
Container(
  height: 50.0,
  width: 150.0,
  child: TextButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.person),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

#### Using SizedBox

```
SizedBox(
  height: 50.0,
  width: 150.0,
  child: TextButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.person),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you.
I made it.
https://dartpad.dev/?id=d74a5764a33998cfae3fd2fa773b5060&null_safety=true

Answer (score 5):

please try with this

```
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red.shade800),
            ),
            child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                child: Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_rounded, size: 18)),
          )
```

Comment: Thank you.
But I want to use a button that have a icon without text.

Comment: updated answer please check. `ElevetedButton.Icon` -Create an elevated button from a pair of widgets that serve as the button's icon and label. So you do not go for `ElevetedButton.Icon`

Answer (score 1):

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.red,fixedSize: Size(100, 50),)
```

Answer (score 0):

the label field is the required field in the `ElevatedButton.icon` widget. But there are other options as well like this:

```
Container(
  height: 50.0,
  width: 100.0,
  child: FlatButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

**EDIT:**

You could use `Container` with `GestureDetector` widget, like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: (){},
  child: Container(
    height: 50.0,
    width: 100.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red
    ),
    child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you.
but flatbutton is deprecated.
I want to use a button that not is deprecated.

Comment: @Jae if you find this correct please mark it as an answer

Comment: You can use MaterialButton instead of FlatButton.
@Jae
Container(
  height: 50.0,
  width: 100.0,
  child: MaterialButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),

Answer (score 0):

```
InkWell(
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                color: Colors.red,),
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          onTap: () {
           
          },
        ),
```